# Running a set of actions before every test-file in mocha

Tags: express, mocha.js

I've started recently working with mocha to test my expressjs server.
My tests are separated to multiple files and most of them contain some duplicated segments (Mostly before statements that load all the fixtures to the DB, etc) and that's really annoying.

I guess I could export them all to a single file and import them on each and every test, but I wonder if there are some more elegant solutions - such as running a certain file that has all the setup commands , and another file that contains all the tear-down commands.

If anyone knows the answer that would be awesome :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are three basic levels of factoring out common functionality for mocha tests. If you want to load in some fixtures once for a bunch of tests (and you've written each test to be independent), use the `before` function to load the fixtures at the top of the file. You can also use `beforeEach` function if you need the fixtures re-initialized each time.

The second option (which is related), is to pull out common functionality into a separate file or set of files and require that file.

Finally, note that mocha has a [root level hook](https://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks):

> You may also pick any file and add "root"-level hooks. For example, add beforeEach() outside of all describe() blocks. This will cause the callback to beforeEach() to run before any test case, regardless of the file it lives in (this is because Mocha has an implied describe() block, called the "root suite").

We use that to start an Express server once (and we use an environment variable so that it runs on a different port than our development server):

```
before(function () {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
  require('../../app.js');
});
```

(We don't need a `done()` here because require is synchronous.) This was, the server is started exactly once, no matter how many different test files include this root-level `before` function.

The advantage of splitting things up in this way is that we can run `npm test` which runs all tests, or run mocha on any specific file or any specific folder, or any specific test or set of tests (using it.only and describe.only) and all of the prerequisites for the selected tests will run.

Comment: Yeah, I do that for my debugging. Every `test/` folder has a root-level `before(){debugger;}` so that I can launch with `debug-brk` and know it will stop when everything is loaded but before it runs

Comment: @dankohn when using `before()` it raises an error `ReferenceError: before is not defined` do you know what can be the issue?

Comment: @Max
Give a look to [this](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1762) to see what is happening. To summarize -r somefile is evaluated by the CLI before Mocha is set up => undefined. I'm not well versed in Mocha but mocho.opts is may be a better solution. If you really want to make it work with -r somefile.js, then add --delay and wrap your setup in [dealyed-oot-suite](https://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite)

Answer (score 12):

Why not `mocha -r <module>` or even using `mocha.opts`?

Have your common file in, say, `init.js` and then run

```
mocha -r `./init`
```

Which will cause mocha to run and load `./init.js` before loading any of the mocha test files.

You could also put it in `mocha.opts` inside your tests directory, and have its contents be

```
--require ./init
```

Comment: I did this and it complains saying 'before' is not defined. I'm basically defining a global 'before' before all tests are run. I've also included 'mocha' but its not working. Any ideas?

Comment: @Salman Hasrat Khan
Give a look to [this](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1762) to see what is happening. To summarize -r somefile is evaluated by the CLI before Mocha is set up => undefined. I'm not well versed in Mocha but mocho.opts is may be a better solution. If you really want to make it work with -r somefile.js, then add --delay and wrap your setup in [dealyed-oot-suite](https://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite)

Comment: Did you mean to use backticks there instead of quotes? That makes the shell evaluate the file as a shell script, not as JavaScript code. Then it tries to open the file given by that shell script's output, so it can be passed to Mocha.